# Method to Increment the value of int row elements in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods

I must create a void method that increments the value of a certain row of a 2D array by 1. The row number is one of the paremeters of the method. For example, if `arr` is `{1, 2}, {3, 3}, {1, 2}`, `increaseValuesOfARowByOne(arr, 3)` outputs `{1, 2}, {3, 3}, {2, 3}`. Here is my code so far:

```
public static void increaseValuesOfARowByOne(int[][] arr, int rowNum)
  {
    for (int k = 0; k < rowNum; k++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
        (arr[rowNum][j])++;
      }

    }
    return;
  }
```

For the example I mentioned above, I end up getting `{1, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}`. In other test cases I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Not sure what to do.

Comment: What are those other test cases?

Comment: Since indexes in Java are 0-based, `increaseValuesOfARowByOne(arr, 3)` would cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` with that 3-row array.

Comment: Remove the first loop `for (int k = 0; k < rowNum; k++)`, why is it even in there?

Comment: you don't need 2 loops, as you don't need to traverse the entire 2D array. Just "go to" `rowNum` and increment it

Comment: That first loop is why the answer is off

Comment: *"Not sure what to do."* **Debug** your code: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

After all the impovements discribed in the comments, you will get something like this:

```
public static void increaseValuesOfARowByOne(int[][] arr, int rowNum) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr[rowNum - 1].length; i++) {
        arr[rowNum - 1][i]++;
    }
}
```